# Sequential continuity on metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

Please give me a hint for proving this statement:

> Let $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ be metric spaces, $f$ a function from $X$ to $Y$. If $f^{-1}(B) $ is closed in $X$ for all closed subset $B$ of $Y$, then $f$ is sequentially continuous.

Note that $f$ is sequentially continuous if and only if for any sequence $(x_n)$, if $d(x_n,x) \to 0$ then $d'(f(x_n),f(x)) \to 0$.

Comment: Uhm, that's the definition of continuity.

Comment: Yes. But I want to prove directly.

Comment: What's the definition of sequentially continuous?

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of sequential continuity, we want to show that if a sequence $\{x_n\}$ converges to $x$ in $X$, then $\{f(x_n)\}$ converges to $f(x)$ in $Y$.

Let $U$ be an open neighborhood of $f(x)$ in $Y$. Then $B:=Y\setminus U$ is closed in $Y$, and $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed in $X$ by assumption. The preimage of a complement is the complement of the preimage, so $f^{-1}(B) = f^{-1}(Y)\setminus f^{-1}(U)$. Since $f$ is defined on all $X$, $f^{-1}(Y) = X$. Since $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed, this means $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$, and it contains $x$. Now it's simply a matter of applying the definitions to find an integer $N$ for which
$$n\geq N\implies x_n\in f^{-1}(U).$$
Hitting this with $f$, we'll see that this $n\geq N\implies f(x_n)\in U$. Our neighborhood about $f(x)$ was arbitrary, so this means $f(x_n)\to f(x)$. If you want to be really technical about it, you can replace the neighborhood with an open ball of a certain radius and rework the proof to suit your needs.

Also notice that much of the work was to show that the preimage of open sets in $Y$ are open in $X$. This is an alternate definition of continuity (and much more common than the "closed preimage" one you gave above). Using this definition from the start cuts down our work significantly.

Comment: You're welcome (if this is what you were looking for, pressing the "check" to accept the answer is appreciated)! As a side note, none of this works if $B$ was just *any* subset of $Y$ (as it is in the definition you gave). I presume that was just a typo, and you meant $B$ to be a closed subset of $Y$?

Comment: Sorry I typed wrong. I will edit right now.